# Python convert date string to python date and subtract

Tags: python

I have a situation where I need to find the previous date from the `date_entry` where the `date_entry` is string, I managed to do this:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta, datetime
>>> from time import strptime, mktime
>>> date_str = '20130723'
>>> date_ = strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d')
>>> date_
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=23, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=204,tm_isdst=-1)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(date_))-timedelta(days=1)
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 22, 0, 0)
>>>
```

But, for this I have to import the modules `timedelta`, `datetime`, `strptime` and `mktime`. I think this really an overkill to solve this simple problem.

Is there any more elegant way to solve this (using Python 2.7) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [datetime.datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) class method:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date_str = '20130723'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d') - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 22, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that we can import strptime from datetime.

Comment: @JohnPrawyn, import strptime?  No, `datetime.datetime.strptime` is different from `time.strptime`.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime` returns datetime object, while `time.strptime` returns `time.struct_time` object.

Answer (score 0):

**Chosen answer is old and works on python 2, returns bellow error for python 3**.

Error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

### Fix + Doing it with PYTHON 3 :

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
date_str = '20130723'
datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d') - timedelta(days=1)
```

Also, use up to date document on **Python 3** here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime